# Can I create a Kotlin extension method for adding an rxJava Subscription to a CompositeSubscription?

Tags: rx-java, kotlin, kotlin-extension, rx-kotlin

I've been playing with Kotlin/RxJava and tried to create an extension method for adding a `Subscription` to a `CompositeSubscription`, that would work like:

```
search.subscribe {
       //do stuff
}.addToComposite(compositeSubscription)
```

This is my attempt so far:

```
fun Subscription.addToComposite(composite: CompositeSubscription) = { composite.add(this) }
```

It compiles and runs without errors but doesn't seem to actually add the `Subscription` to the `CompositeSubscription`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: please mark the question as closed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is defined incorrectly. Compare:

```
fun f() { println("hello") }
```

This function executes the single statement `println("hello")` and is a simple [`Unit`-returning function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#unit-returning-functions) (same to `void` in Java).

```
fun g() = { println("hello") }
```

This function is a [single-expression function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions), it just returns value of expression 
`{ println("hello") }`, that is a [lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions). `g`'s return type is `() -> Unit`, *and it doesn't execute the lambda body!*

This is also [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037442/kotlin-function-declaration-equals-sign-before-curly-braces/).

---

To fix your code, you can just remove `=` from your function declaration:

```
fun Subscription.addToComposite(composite: CompositeSubscription) { composite.add(this) }
```