# Kotlin function declaration: equals sign before curly braces

Tags: function, kotlin

In Kotlin, the function declaration syntax allows you to write equals sign before the curly braces.

Consider these two examples:

1. Without `=` sign:

```kotlin
fun foo1() {
    println("baz1")
}
```

The code inside the body gets executed by just calling `foo1()`.

2. With `=` sign:

```kotlin
fun foo2() = {
    println("baz2")
}
```

Here, when `foo2()` is called, nothing happens, but to get the body executed one can write `foo2()()`.

What is the difference in these two declarations and **why do they behave differently?**

You can run the code using the following program:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    foo1()
    foo2()
}

/*
This code example produces the following results:
baz1
*/
```

---

<sup>This question, though having not much meaning, is [intentionally asked and answered by the author][1], because a few questions have already been posted where people got problems because of incorrect function definitions.</sup>

Comment: Kotlin or the IDE should probably have an inspection for that. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11461

Comment: My problem was about braces appearing after a function call. [This](https://medium.com/@s.badamestani/lambda-in-kotlin-a6fc055a2c88) medium article explains the varying syntactical alternatives.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Despite visual similarity, the idea of these two declarations is completely different.

### 1. Function declaration without equals sign

Function declaration without equals sign is a [`Unit`-returning function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#unit-returning-functions) (similar to Java's `void` functions).

What's inside the curly braces is its body, which gets executed right on the function call. The function can be rewritten with `Unit` explicitly specified:

```kotlin
fun foo1(): Unit {
    println("baz1")
    return Unit
}
```

Kotlin doesn't require the return statement and explicit return type for `Unit`-returning functions, and both are usually omitted.

### 2. Function declaration with equals sign

Function declaration with equals sign is a [single-expression function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions), and what it does is just return what's to the right of equals sign.

A simpler example: `fun getInt() = 1` is just a shorter form of `fun getInt(): Int { return 1 }`.

In `foo2`, the right hand side is [a lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions) expression. The code inside the lambda code block is **not executed**. In other words, `foo2` is a function that returns another function.

Return type of `foo2` is `() -> Unit`, a function itself, and thus `foo2` is a [higher-order function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions).

Without the syntactic sugar and with explicit type, `foo2` can be rewritten as

```kotlin
fun foo2(): () -> Unit {
    val result: () -> Unit = { println("baz2") }
    return result
}
```

As to the usage, the function which `foo2` returns can be stored in a variable, passed around and **can later be invoked**:

```kotlin
val f = foo2()
f() //equivalent to
f.invoke()
```

This is also why `foo2()()` in the example executes the code from the lambda body.

Alternatively, we can add `()` at the end when we declare foo2(), as shown in the following example. As such, the lambda expression will be invoked when calling `foo3()`. But this is **not** a good pattern.

```kotlin
fun foo3() = {
    println("baz3")
}()
```