# Kotlin: function parameters sent in but not executed?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code that pass in an Integer and two functions.

```
choseNavigation(childPos, {Toast.makeText(ctx, "hello1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()},
                                {Toast.makeText(ctx, "hello2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()})
```

The function definition as below:

```
private fun choseNavigation(pos: Int, action1: () -> Unit, action2: () -> Unit) {
    when(pos) {
        0-> {
            action1
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "hello-again1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        1->{
            action2
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "hello-again2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

When my childPost is 0, I expect it to Toast `hello1` and `hello-again1`. And when it is 1, I expect it to Toast `hello2` and `hello-again2`.

However, when I run the function, it only toast `hello-again1` or `hello-again2`. The sent in function is not being activated at all. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to actually invoke your lambdas with `()`:

```
...
action1()
Toast.makeText(ctx, "hello-again1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
...
```

For the additional information on why lambdas need to be invoked: cannot explain it better than @hotkey [did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36037443/4096987).

Comment: Nice! If we call without the parenthesis, why does Kotlin allow that syntactically? Does it meant to achieve some other thing?

Comment: @Elye, in Kotlin, statements consisting of single expression can call getters of properties (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html). But probably there might be a warning for definitely useless statements.